# problem in android studio. my SDK is not downloaded or corrupted

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

so , I am a programmer who is young , but developed some windows apps.
[click on this to see my last app i developed.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1td0yI341x9YK4KPlwTxRd726WF64Id8T/view?usp=sharing)

and I want to learn android programming. i have downloaded the android studio but when i want to open a new project it says "your android SDK is corrupted or not downloaded"
can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `SDK Manager` uninstall and reinstall the SDK tools and platforms

Comment: ummm... i get to SDK manager but i didn't see any uninstall button. where  is it?

Comment: uncheck the components to uninstall them